# Como faço um pendrive mudar meu background quando plugo ele no pc?

Tags: python, windows, script, batch, usb

Eu já tentei usar esses códigos:

```
@echo off
set patch= D:\wallpaper.bmp
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d %patch% /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
if not exist C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes
md CachedFiles
end if
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles
dir /b >C:\Users\%username%\AppData\file.tmp
set /p name=<C:\Users\%username%\AppData\file.tmp
del C:\Users\%username%\AppData\file.tmp
del %name%
copy "%patch%" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles"
dir /b >C:\Users\%username%\AppData\file.tmp
set /p newname=<C:\Users\%username%\AppData\file.tmp
del C:\Users\%username%\AppData\file.tmp
ren %newname% %name%
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters


@echo off
reg /add HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WallPaper /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d c:\images\wallpaper.bmp
```

sempre tenho que executar mais de uma vez para funcionar, ou apenas para de funcionar. Então eu tenho que atualizar a pasta onde a imagem esta.

Comment: Amigo, não consegui entender muito bem - tu queres trocar o papel de parede do teu Windows quanto tu pluga o Pen-drive? Ou é algum outro background específico (alguma tela, aplicação, etc)?

Comment: só o background normal